# Cannot authenticate to twitter, facebook, linkedin in "Internet Accounts" MBP OSX 10.9.4

Tags: internet, accounts, facebook, twitter

OSX Mavericks 10.9.4 on an MBP

I cannot authenticate to any social network from the "Internet Accounts" in System Preferences, usually the response is:  "Unable to verify account name or password"
(I have checked these credentials at the websites for the appropriate networks)

Here is an example result from the system.log:

```
Jul 17 14:48:15 apa com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice[3953]: *** accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:com.apple.facebook returned nil
Jul 17 14:48:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul 17 14:48:15 apa com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice[3953]: -[IAAccount initWithProviderType:loginName:] [358] -- *** Missing parameter. provider = com.apple.account.facebook; loginName = (null)
Jul 17 14:48:15 apa com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice[3953]: *** accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:com.apple.facebook returned nil
```

I have verified and tried facebook, twitter, linkedin, and flickr.  I mostly just want to integrate these services into the notification center.

Has anyone seen this behavior (failure for all social networks)?  Any fixes?  Thanks for looking...

Answer (score 1):

I looked in my logs and I get a different reply... seems that the linkedin processes/api have changed

```
Jul 31 19:07:20 --- last message repeated 9 times ---
Jul 31 19:07:20 baksons.local accountsd[259]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAccountStore.m - -[ACDAccountStore verifyCredentialsForAccount:saveWhenAuthorized:withHandler:] - 1413 - com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice (com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice) is trying to verify account credentials for account: peter.bakker@alumni.insead.edu
Jul 31 19:07:21 baksons.local accountsd[259]: (null) - (null) - 0 - Request status was 500
Jul 31 19:07:21 baksons.local accountsd[259]: /SourceCache/Social/Social-279.11/LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationPlugin/LinkedInAuthenticationPlugin.m - __65-[LinkedInAuthenticationPlugin _authenticateAccount:withHandler:]_block_invoke - 262 - Access token request failed. Response: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <style type="text/css">
    html, body, h2, p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background: #f2f2f2;
      font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    #header {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #252525;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #303030;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #303030;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px #303030;
    }
    #header .logo {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 15%;
      top: 6px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #header .logo  img {
      border: 0;
    }

    #content {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 80px auto 0;
      text-align: center;
      color: #333;
    }
    #content a,
    #content a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #0077B5;
      outline: none;
    }
    #content h2 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 40px;
      color: #333;
    }
    #content #en_US h2 {
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    #content .message,
    #content .status,
    #content .twitter,
    #content .blog {
      display: block;
    }
    #content .alternatives {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 0 74px;
      line-height: 32px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #content #wiper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 240px;
      height: 295px;
      background: url(http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/photos/error_pages/photo_clean-in_974x295_v1.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    }

    #footer {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 40px auto 0;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      overflow: auto;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #888;
    }
    #footer .copyright {
      float: left;
    }
    #footer .error-id {
      float: right;
    }

    </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.className += ' js';
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="header">
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="logo"><img src="//static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/logo_linkedin_flat_white_98x25.png" alt="LinkedIn"/></a>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
        <div id="en_US">
          <h2>
            <span class="message">We're getting things cleaned up.</span>
            <span class="status">We'll be back soon.</span>
          </h2>
          <p class="alternatives">
            <span class="twitter">Follow <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/redir/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter%2Ecom%2FLinkedInHelp&urlhash=_uru">@LinkedInHelp</a> on Twitter to get site availability updates.</span>
            <span class="blog">In the meantime, learn what's new at LinkedIn by <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog%2Elinkedin%2Ecom&urlhash=uHTj">visiting our blog</a>.</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="wiper"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
        <p class="copyright">
          &copy; 2013 LinkedIn Corporation
        </p>
          <p class="error-id">
            Error Id: 140679763152567
          </p>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
Jul 31 19:07:21 baksons.local accountsd[259]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAccountStore.m - __70-[ACDAccountStore saveAccount:pid:verify:dataclassActions:completion:]_block_invoke539 - 1362 - Could not verify account: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 3.)
Jul 31 19:07:21 baksons.local WindowServer[102]: window 4fd is already attached to window 4fb
Jul 31 19:07:26 --- last message repeated 9 times ---
Jul 31 19:07:26 baksons.local Preview[74667]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFFFFFFFFFECC) from font server
Jul 31 19:07:50 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```